# Sequelize Postgresql didn't force foreign constraint

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have these models. (tickets and events). The event has many tickets and a ticket belongs to one event.

models/ticket.js

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Ticket extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Ticket.belongsTo(models.Event, {
        foreignKey: "event_id",
        as: "event"
      })

      Ticket.hasMany(models.Order, {
        foreignKey: "ticket_id",
        as: "orders"
      })
    }
  };
  Ticket.init({
    ticket_type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "Ticket type is required" } }
    },
    event_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "event_id is required" } }
    },
    ticket_quota: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, default: 0
    },
    ticket_price: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT, default: 1
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Ticket',
  });
  return Ticket;
};
```

models/event.js

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Event extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Event.hasMany(models.Ticket, {
        foreignKey: "event_id",
        as: "tickets"
      })
    }
  };
  Event.init({
    event_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "Event name is required" } }
    },
    event_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false, validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "Event Date is required" } }
    },
    event_location: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "Event location is required" } }
    },
    event_description: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Event',
  });
  return Event;
};
```

As can be seen here that ticket is associated with the event. The problem is when I tried to insert a ticket with event_id that doesn't exist in the event table. It still inserted despite the constraint.

Anyone knows whats wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `allowNull: false` on your association.

```
  // define association here
  Event.hasMany(models.Ticket, {
    foreignKey: "event_id",
    as: "tickets",
    allowNull: false,
  })
```

Comment: added but the ticket is still inserted @doublesharp

Comment: @Sam did you generate a new db? If the database already exists you might need to run a migration to add the relationship if it wasn't there when the tables where created. I have an event ticketing site btw :)

Comment: the command is sequelize db:migrate right or I need to create a new migration for it. that's great!

Answer (score 0):

Last Resort Solution :

Ended up with migration:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /**
     * Add altering commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
     */
    queryInterface.removeColumn("Tickets",'event_id')
    queryInterface.removeColumn("Orders",'ticket_id')
    queryInterface.removeColumn("Orders",'user_id')

    queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Tickets', // name of Source model
      'event_id', // name of the key we're adding 
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Events', // name of Target model
          key: 'id', // key in Target model that we're referencing
        },
        allowNull: false,
        validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "event_id is required" }},
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
      }
    );

    queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Orders', // name of Source model
      'user_id', // name of the key we're adding 
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users', // name of Target model
          key: 'id', // key in Target model that we're referencing
        },
        allowNull: false,
        validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "user_id is required" }},
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
      }
    );

    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Orders', // name of Source model
      'ticket_id', // name of the key we're adding 
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Tickets', // name of Target model
          key: 'id', // key in Target model that we're referencing
        },
        allowNull: false,
        validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "ticket_id is required" }},
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
      }
    );
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /**
     * Add reverting commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
     */

    queryInterface.removeColumn("Tickets",'event_id')
    queryInterface.removeColumn("Orders",'ticket_id')
    queryInterface.removeColumn("Orders",'user_id')

    queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Tickets', // name of Source model
      'event_id', // name of the key we're adding 
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "event_id is required" }},
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
      }
    );

    queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Orders', // name of Source model
      'user_id', // name of the key we're adding 
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "user_id is required" }},
      }
    );

    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Orders', // name of Source model
      'ticket_id', // name of the key we're adding 
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: { notNull: { args: true, msg: "ticket_id is required"}}
      }
    );

  }
};
```